# Multiple checkboxes to toggle related div

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I've tried to look around other very similar questions but none seem to have a solution.

How would I go about achieving the following scenario:

**Layout:**

```
Checkbox 1 "Orange"  
Checkbox 2 "Apple"  
Checkbox 3 "Banana"  

Div 1 "Orange"  
Div 2 "Apple"  
Div 3 "Banana"
```

When you load the page, all you can see is the checkboxes. When the user selects a checkbox, the corresponding div is displayed. If the user then selects another checkbox, the original div is hidden and the newly selected one is displayed.

I can only use a checkbox as it's for another purpose whereby checkbox is the desired option.

My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false).change();
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($(this).attr("type") === "checkbox") {
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("selected");
            $("#" + name).toggle(this.checked);
        }
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: Surely a radio would be a much better fit for this scenario? A checkbox implies that you can select multiple at once and have multiple divs visible.

Comment: Revisiting the scope, I actually think a radio button would indeed be better.

Comment: it would be easier if u add a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{   var temp_id = '';
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
       var div_id = $(this).val();

        if(temp_id == '') temp_id = div_id;
        else
        {
            $('#' + temp_id).hide();
            temp_id = div_id;
        }

        $('#' + div_id).show(); 

    });
});
```

---

```
<input type="radio" name="rd" value="orange">Orange
<input type="radio" name="rd" value="apple">Apple
<input type="radio" name="rd" value="banana">Banana
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This: 
I have not test it. Let me know is heving issue in it. :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    jQuery('.toggle input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('.toggle input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked","false");
        jQuery(this).prop("checked","true");

        jQuery(".toggle div").hide();
        var div_index = jQuery(this).index();
        jQuery(".toggle div:eq("+div_index+")").show();

    }
}
```